# Javascript object method returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I am following the headfirst javascript programming book and I am building the battleship game.  I wrote a function to be used as an object method. The function returns properly but when I try to use it as an object method it returns undefined. Why?

Here's the function:

```
function parseGuess(guess) {
  var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
  if (guess === null || guess.length !== 2) {
    alert("Oops! Please enter a letter and a number on the board.");
  } else {
    var row = alphabet.indexOf(guess.charAt(0));
    var column = guess.charAt(1);

    if (isNaN(row) || isNaN(column)) {
      alert("Oops! This isn't on the board.");
    } else if (
      row < 0 ||
      row >= model.boardSize ||
      column < 0 ||
      column >= model.boardSize
    ) {
      alert("Oops! That's off the board.");
    } else {
      return row + column;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(parseGuess("G6"));  return 66;
```

Here's the object's method:

```
var controller = {
  guesses: 0,

  processGuess: function (guess) {
    var location = parseGuess(guess);
    if (location) {
      this.guesses++;
      var hit = model.fire(location);
      if (hit && model.shipsSunk === model.numShips) {
        view.displayMessage(
          "You sank all my battleships, in " + this.guesses + " guesses"
        );
      }
    }
  },
};
```

I was expecting the same result from the function as the object method

Comment: _"I was expecting the same result from the function as the object method"_... what makes you think they're different? Did you try debugging the value you get for `location`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce any problem ~ https://jsfiddle.net/p5bfo1g0/. `model.fire()` is called with the same value as returned by `parseGuess()`

Comment: set a break point and walk through and see what is differet.